# Show that the marginal probability $P(X = x)$ is given by:

Tags: probability, marginal-probability

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ take integer values $x$ and $y$, both $≥ 1$, and such that $2x + y ≤ 2a$, where a is an integer greater than $1$. The joint probability within this region is given by:

$$P(X=x,Y =y)=c(2x+y)$$

where c is a constant and it is zero elsewhere.

Show that the marginal probability $P (X = x)$ is given by:

$$P(X=x) = \frac{6(a−x)(2x+2a+1)}{a(a−1)(8a+5)}$$

How do I calculate the value of $c$?

[image]

Comment: You should not use integrals. Your variables are discrete (they take values in the integers) , you are given a probability funcion (not a density!).

Comment: how do i solve it without the integrals?

Comment: Please explain what you get when you try to compute the relevant sums.

Comment: @Did I updated the question to show my computation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don’t need to use the integrals to solve this problem, noting that x is discrete.

$P(x=k)=\sum_{t=1}^{2a-2k}{P(x=k, y=t)} $

Which will lead to the final answer.

Comment: I do not get the correct answer when I do this. I get $2c*(a - k) (2k + t)$ for this expression.

Comment: @Pete There’s other details you need to fill up. Like how to get c from the distribution. Besides you must have made some mistake cause there shouldn’t be a “t” when you complete the sum

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake and now I get c*(2*a^2 + a - 2*k^2 - k) which looks like the numerator. I guess c will get me the denominator.